# Inaccurate Flag Indicator

Tags: bug, moderator-tools, flags

I started seeing a small bug with the flag indicator this morning.  When opened Drupal Answers today, there were a few flags.  I handled some, and noticed that the count in the header and the count on **Moderator Tools** page wasn't the same:

[image]

This has happened a few times on different machines, and after shift-reloads.

Comment: Could be a flag on a post by yourself - we wouldn't show it to you in such a case.

Comment: Hmmm.  I'll check with the other mods to see if this was the case.

Comment: @oder I have seen similar behaviour today, looked like excessive caching.

Comment: The answer is always "caching".

Comment: @oded So the functionality is to suppress flags against elected mod self-content in the flag detail section and not the flag count section?

Comment: Same thing happening for me on Drupal Answers

Comment: @MPD As moderator, you can always see if any of your post have been flagged, and the flag handled: Click on the orange circle with a number in http://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/835/mpd, the one between "mod" and "edit."

Comment: @Oded Are flags against one's own posts *really* never shown? Even for moderators? I highly doubt that's the case and recall seeing otherwise.

Comment: @slhck - It is the case when a mod flags a post it will not appear to the mod in the mod queue. Guess my earlier comment was a bit off.

Comment: @Oded As moderator, I can handle a flag I raised. It happened that I raised a flag for an answer given to a question I answered too, and I was able to see that flag; I was also able to set it as helpful or decline it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Caching. No, really.

Basically, the code to query the current number of flags has been getting a bit slow lately (as in... *slooooooow*); this only affects ♦ moderators, but on big sites like stackoverflow it was **very** painful. We've known for a while that the flags storage needs some love, and we have a big refactor under way to do *exactly that* (which will solve the performance problem *properly*), due to deliver some goodness in a few weeks. So... we were a bit reluctant to invest a large amount of effort *in parallel to that*, to fix up the slowness.

So: as a short term measure (while we wait for that work to complete), we've disabled the one line of code that clears the cache every time something gets flagged (or a flag gets resolved). It will still update automatically every minute, so *on average* you will only see the incorrect value for 30 seconds. But this quick fix makes the site a lot less unpleasant for ♦ moderators to navigate.

We hope to turn this back on when the *sane* model for flags completes.

Comment: If it would be easy to do, hardcoding this to only apply to SO would be very nice. The SO mods don't care about a current flag counter anyway, and all other sites should not have any significant performance problems due to flags.

Comment: So, [meta-tag:status-our-fault]? :)

Comment: @MadScientist I did think about that yesterday, but concluded "keep it simple" - but tell you what... since you asked nicely, I'll give it a whirl just disabled on SO; next deploy

Comment: @MarcGravell Thanks for re-enabling this. Perhaps that one line of code could only invalidate the cache if the total count was < 3 or something so that small sites would not get a lonely 1 and large sites would basically ride the once a minute update cycle? No worries if you have a real fix coming "real soon now".