# Flag indicator not always showing on the home page

Tags: bug, moderator-tools, top-bar

I am not sure if this is the same problem as [Inaccurate Flag Indicator](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182166) or [Flag indicator present on Meta, but no flags visible](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/187216), but the symptoms I am seeing are a little different.

Peridically, when I visit Drupal Answers (normally via my bookmark to /questions?sort=newest), I will not see a flag indicator up in the header.  If I click on another link on the site, I will then see the indicator if there is an unhandled flag.  The indicator will then be there until for the rest of my time on the site.

This has happened enough times for me to think this isn't a fluke.  But, with the flag frequency we see, it it a little hard to really determine if this is a real problem.  If I had to guess, I think this started happening about a week ago.

Comment: I also see similar behavior on Server Fault. The flag indicators never _automatically_ appear; I have to reload the page, or go to another page.

Comment: Is this only happening to you with flags? I've noticed in the last week or so that I have to refresh twice to get any new content to load. I'll also be on the /questions?sort=newest page, on ELL, and if I refresh once no new questions display. I refresh again and new questions & the flag indicator appear (if there are flags).

Comment: The flag indicator and the suggested edit indicator. I have no problem seeing the notification of new questions while on /questions (as long as I'm on page 1).

Comment: It's a new bug that has cropped up recently, not sure when of if it is fixed, since it comes and goes.