# Zombie moderator flag after account deletion?

Tags: support, bug, flags, moderator-tools

*Edit*: The flag is now gone.  It disappeared at almost exactly 30 minutes after my last moderation action.  I still believe this may represent a bug and not a typical caching issue.

---

- I am properly signed in with a moderator account;
- There is a flag notification symbol, but I cannot view the flag.
- This state has remained for over 20 minutes.

Possible cause: I handled a post that was flagged for spam by destroying the spam-bot account.
Perhaps this caused the flag to fall into the void and leave a ghost behind.

[image]

Comment: caching, always caching

Comment: u sure cache is cleared?????

Comment: @Zaheer And how do I do that?  I've refreshed the page, even restarted the browser, and it's still there.

Comment: @ZaheerAhmed Even if *his* cache is cleared, it's likely cached on the server side.  There isn't much of a solution but to wait a bit.

Comment: try another browser....

Comment: @Servy So this happens for minutes at a time?  I thought such caching was very short term.  This has been there for probably about ten minutes now.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182166/inaccurate-flag-indicator?rq=1 ?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard The time it takes cache items to expire can very widely based on implementation.  I'm not surprised in the least for it to be cached for 10 minutes.

Comment: @Bart That would only apply to non-mods.  The OP is a mod, so he *should* see that flag.

Comment: @Mat That looks like a duplicate, but I note that the flag indicator (1) is displayed in two different places on my site; I don't know if this is significant or merely the design.

Comment: @Servy Well this is the first time I can recall it happening and I've been a community moderator for more than a year.

Comment: Yeah. Looks a bit too persistent too. Note that there was some "indexing weirdness" that caused flagging issues on SO this week-end. Might be tweaking things in that area? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194581/cant-close-questions-all-of-a-sudden

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Caching issues crop up pretty much every single day, in various places.  Sometimes, for whatever reason, something takes longer than expected to be updated.  Possibly due to an overworked server, possibly a time when the cache should have been forced to refresh the update gets dropped on the floor, etc.  It happens.  Don't freak out.  Give it time.  If it becomes a frequent and debilitating problem, it can be addressed.  If it's a flag count being off by one for a few minutes, it can be pretty safely ignored.

Comment: @Servy Okay, thanks.  I don't mean to freak out but rather to be diligent about reporting bugs to the proper handlers.

Comment: So we can now expect three flags resolution: declined, helpful, _undead_?

Comment: @Mat The flag has disappeared.  Caching after all I guess, but I borrowed from your comment in updating my question title. :-)

Comment: @Mat declined, helpful, vitality not found.