# Where has my flag gone? I want to handle it

Tags: bug, flags, moderator-tools

#### Where has my flag gone? I want to handle it.

The top bar is showing there is a flag to handle. When I click on the blue button I see this:

[image]

Where is my flag hiding?

Note I have refreshed the page several times.

Can I blame caching? (Normally caching is not an issue in flag handling)

Comment: The title of the tab does show that there are 0 flags, so at least that is correct

Comment: Might be [this issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194713/zombie-moderator-flag-after-account-deletion). (TL;DR: flag by a deleted user)