# Post flagged for moderator attention is missing

Tags: bug, flags, moderator-tools

#### Where has the flagged post gone?

[image: Screenshot showing a "1" flag notification in the top bar and in the moderator tools tabs, but a blank flag queue]

Comment: [Where has my flag gone? I want to handle it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/364073/295232)

Comment: @Glorfindel lol. I don't remember asking that :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that [I should blame caching](https://shouldiblamecaching.com/) as the flag indicator disappeared after a few minutes

Comment: Always blame caching.  That is the source of all problems on the internet.

Comment: Relevant: https://shouldiblamecaching.com/